# Nginx rewrite nextcloud index.php in url

Tags: nginx, rewrite, nextcloud

How to I rewrite the the index.php in the [nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) url on a [nginx webserver](https://nginx.org)?

For example my login url looks like that at the moment:

```
https://clouddomain.ltd/index.php/login/
```

and should be rewriten to

```
https://clouddomain.ltd/login/
```

I've tried several suggestions from [serverfalt](https://serverfault.com) but without success.

My nginx config looks like that:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/clouddomain.ltdcrt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/clouddomain.ltdkey;
    set $root_path "/media/storage/nextcloud";
    root $root_path;
    index index.php;
    set $socket "unix:/var/run/fpm-759c4785-ef9f904a4833.sock";
    access_log /var/log/nginx/storage-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/storage-error.log;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
    client_max_body_size 10G; # set max upload size
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;
    rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;
    error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location ~ ^/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
        deny all;
    }
    location / {
        # The following 2 rules are only needed with webfinger
        rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
        rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;
        rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
        rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;
        rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;
        rewrite ^ /index.php$uri;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
    }
    location ~ ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
        try_files $1 = 404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $2;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_pass $socket;
    }
    # Optional: set long EXPIRES header on static assets
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
        expires 30d;
        # Optional: Don't log access to assets
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

Comment: The URLs on the pages output by NextCloud are generated by the application, you need to find the way in NextCloud, as nginx doesn't modify the output sent to it by the application.

Comment: I already checked, but all option I could found seem only to work with an apache server.

Comment: If there is a way in NextCloud, it works the same both for nginx and Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to correct the last section where it tells `nginx` how to pass the `php` files to `php-fpm`.

Here is my final config for the moment:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/clouddomain.ltdcrt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/clouddomain.ltdkey;
    set $root_path "/media/storage/nextcloud";
    root $root_path;
    index index.php;
    set $socket "unix:/var/run/fpm-759c4785-ef9f904a4833.sock";
    access_log /var/log/nginx/storage-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/storage-error.log;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";

    # Set max upload size
    client_max_body_size 10G; 
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    # Disable gzip to avoid the removal of the ETag header
    gzip off;

    # Only use index.php for the index page
    index index.php;

    # Use pretty error pages
    error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

    # If robots.txt is present, always allow access and serve it directly
    # If it isn't, don't log the access attempt
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Deny access to the data and config directories, .ht* files,
    # the README, and the database structure definition
    location ~ ^/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
        deny all;
    }

    # Pretty URLs for WebDAV
    location ~* \/remote\/(?:.*)$ {
        rewrite ^ /remote.php last;
    }

    # Rewrite file preview requests and requests for the JS configuration file
    # to the nextcloud front controller
    location ~* \/core\/(?:js\/oc\.js|preview\.png).*$ {
        rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }

    # Main location block
    # Most requests will fall into this block
    location / {
        # Specific rewrites for WebDAV/CalDAV/CardDAV and documentation
        rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
        rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
        rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;
        # The following 2 rules are only needed with webfinger
        rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
        rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;
        rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
        rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;
        rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

        # Exclude static assets, specific PHP files, and Let's Encrypt verifications,
        # then rewrite everything else to the ownCloud front controller
        if ($uri !~* (?:\.(?:css|js|svg|gif|png|html|ttf|woff)$|^\/(?:remote|public|cron|status|ocs\/v1|ocs\/v2)\.php|^\/\.well-known\/acme-challenge\/.*$)){
            rewrite ^ /index.php last;
        }

    }

    # Set a long expires header on static assets, excluding files accessed through WebDAV
    # This block will break uploads to WebDAV for the listed file extensions without the negative lookahead
    location ~* ^(?!\/remote\.php)(?:.*)\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf|html|svg|ttf|woff)$ {
        expires 30d;
        # Optional: Don't log access to assets
        access_log off;
    }    

    # Pass PHP files to PHP-FPM for processing
    location ~ ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
        try_files $1 = 404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $2;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        # Tell nextcloud we're rewriting URLs
        fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
        fastcgi_pass $socket;
    }       

}
```

Source: https://help.nextcloud.com/t/pretty-urls-for-nextcloud-11-with-nginx-and-php5/11921/3

Comment: This is not working anymore. I'm getting a 404 error page